# TYPO3 using TCA in class

Tags: php, typo3

When I check TCA in backend I have structure like that.

```
fe_users
  columns
    many columns...
```

When I use `$GLOBALS['TCA']['fe_users']['columns']` in the code I get `NULL`.
If I call `t3lib_div::loadTCA('fe_users')` before $GLOBALS then I get some of the columns but still not all of them.

I have in ext_tables.php

```
t3lib_div::loadTCA('fe_users');
t3lib_extMgm::addTCAcolumns('fe_users',$tempColumns,1);
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users','columnname', '', 'after:disable');
```

How can I reach the rest of the columns?

Thanks

Comment: Which columns are missing when you use `t3lib_div::loadTCA('fe_users')`?

Comment: Those I added in ext_tables.php

Comment: Check the order of the loaded extensions in ``extList`` of ``localconf.php``, if you load the TCA before the new values have been written, they will not appear.

Comment: It is the last one in the `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList']` variable. But I do not know where the TCA is loaded.

Comment: @tttpapi: Where are you trying to access those columns? In a backend module or in a frontend one?

Comment: @cascaval In front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code at the beginning of the frontend method where you want to access the TCA settings:

```
global $TCA;
tslib_fe::includeTCA();
t3lib_div::loadTCA('fe_users');
```

Then you can access the TCA settings in the `$TCA` array.